# fread Reading No More than 8192 Bytes

Tags: php, io, stream, php-7

I'm having a weird issue where fread is refusing to read more than 8192 bytes. I know this is expected behavior for remote streams that are read buffered, but this is a local .zip file created by a PHP script.

Code example:

```
$fh = fopen('/path/to/file.zip', 'rb');
$data = fread($fh, 4194304); // 4 MB
echo strlen($data);
```

Outputs: 8192

The file itself is 9 mb in size.

If I run this in CLI, it works fine.

PHP version is 7.1.

Any idea why I'd be getting this issue?

Comment: "*If I run this in CLI, it works fine.*" So, in which context you observe the described behaviour?

Comment: @Paolo Web server.

Comment: Citation needed for "expected behavior for remote streams"

Answer (score -1):

according to the [docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) that's what it does:

> if the stream is read buffered and it does not represent a plain file,
>   at most one read of up to a number of bytes equal to the chunk size
>   (usually 8192) is made; depending on the previously buffered data, the
>   size of the returned data may be larger than the chunk size.

Comment: Yes only if it's a stream, not just for local files. I've tested in other environments and it can read more than 8192 bytes.